# Grouped bar chart where y values are distinct vector names

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a`data.frame` such as:

```
df <- data.frame(region = c(rep("r1", 5), rep("r2", 5)),
                 family = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3",
                            "B1", "B6", "B11", "B2", "B2"),
                 genus = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", "a1",
                           "b1", "b3", "b3", "b1", "b4"),
                 spp = c("a1a", "a4a", "a2a", "a1a", "a1a",
                         "b1b", "b6b", "b6b", "b2b", "b3b"))
```

I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart such as the following image
[image]

Where each color is respectively `family`, `genus`, and `spp` and "R1"/"R2 are `region`. The `N` axis must be the `n_distinct()` of `family`, `genus`, and `spp`. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your data into shape:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

plot_df  <- df  |>
    group_by(region)  |>
    summarise(across(family:spp, n_distinct))  |>
    pivot_longer(-region)

plot_df
# A tibble: 6 x 3    
#   region name   value
#   <chr>  <chr>  <int>
# 1 r1     family     3
# 2 r1     genus      2
# 3 r1     spp        3
# 4 r2     family     4
# 5 r2     genus      3
# 6 r2     spp        4
```

Then you can plot it:

```r
ggplot(plot_df) + 
    geom_col(mapping = aes(
        x = name,
        y = value,
        fill = name
    )) +
    facet_wrap(vars(region)) +
    labs(
        y = "n",
        title = "Number of distinct whatever"
    ) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank()
    ) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette=3)
```

[image]

*Edit: made the plot look slightly nicer.*

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. I was having some issues in the pre-ploting

Answer (score 2):

You can plot `region` directly on the x axis without faceting too:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(df, family:spp, names_to = 'level') %>%
  group_by(region, level) %>% 
  summarize(n = n_distinct(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(region, n, color = level)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), width = 0.5,
           fill = 'white', size = 3) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#ff7f27', '#a349a4', '#ffaec9'))
```

[image]

Comment: I read somewhere once that it's good to stop the viewer's eye from flitting between legend and bars if you can avoid it, which I try to do, but I will admit that this answer better answers the actual question.

Comment: @SamR I agree with the notion of avoiding a legend where you can. This was more a bit of fun, emulating the style of the hand-drawn plot. Facets work better here.

Comment: I'm actually impressed that you did the bar charts in a literal way. Didn't even think about someone going this way. Thanks too. Saving it for plotting ideas.

Comment: @hiperhiper I think your palette choice is pretty nice actually. I think this style of plot would work well in some informal settings.